# Android directory path confusion

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I'd like to get the path to a certain directory in Android.

I ended up using the Android 6+ default file manager to select a certain directory like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 1);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File directory = new File(data.getData().getPath());
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);  // files is becomes null
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, I get a path like `/tree/downloads` for the download directory. Which results in an invalid path and an exception.

What would be the correct way to access the path?

EDIT:

So after an hour of coffee and research, I came to the conclusion that there is no good way of doing what I want. While there are several workarounds, all I tested expect a file resource instead of a directory and thus result in a fatal exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads`.

However, in my case I want the directory to get the files.

So therefore I'm defaulting to just using the public storage directories provided by Android, where it is easy to get the path. If someone's got a generic solution that works for any kind of directory, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `I get a path like /tree/downloads` No. You get  a 'content scheme' like `content:// .......`. Use `data.getData().toString()` to see. You cannot use the File class to access it.

Comment: Well, yes I'm aware of that. I know it's an Uri and that an Uri isn't necessarily a file/path. However, I need the path, that's why I'm having the File Manager in the first place, in that way I don't need the "content" and I guess I'm also guaranteed that whatever I get will be a path in that scenario.

Comment: Why do you need a file scheme? Why cant you work with a content scheme? You can list files and directories too starting with a content scheme. Modern times have come. Join the club as files will disappear.

Comment: `that's why I'm having the File Manager ` Wrong name. Its more a content manager.

Comment: You can write your own file picker or download a ready to use file picker class. There are several available.

Comment: How do I use the content scheme? Basically what I need are all files in a selected directory as java.io.File.

Comment: You will NOT get them for use with the File class. Can you finally tell why you think you need to work with the File class? The only valid reason is that you use a library you did not write yourself and the library is for File.

Comment: Exactly this. The library expects File. I might try to work around it given the time to do so but atm I'm stuck with it.